# A problem about Riesz's Lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I am thinking in this problem:

> If $E$ is a normed space and $M\subseteq E$ is a subspace of finite dimension, prove that for all $x\in E-M$ there exists $m_0\in M$ such that $d(x,M)=\|x-m_0\|$.

I am trying to apply Riesz's Theorem because $M$ is a closed space (finite dimensional), but I don't know how....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One answer is already given using sequences.Alternatively,since $M$ is closed(because it's finite dimensional) and $x$ doesn't belong to $M$,we have $d(x,M)>0$.Let $d(x,M)=k$ and $B_{x}$ denote the closed ball of radius $2k$ centered at $x$.Let $S=M\cap B_{x}$.Since $M$ is finite dimensional,$S$ is compact,and hence,the continuous map $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(y)=||y-x||$ for all $y$ in $S$ attains it's infimum,which is $k$,at some $y_{0}$ in $S$.

Answer (score 5):

By definition of distance, there exists $\{m_n\}\subset M$ such that $\|x-m_n\|\to d(x,M)$.  From the triangle inequality, 
$$
\|m_n\|\leq\|x-m_n\|+\|x\|.
$$
So the sequence $\{m_n\}$ is bounded. Because $M$ is finite-dimensional, it is closed, and also closed balls are compact. So there exists a convergent subsequence $m_{n_k}$. Let $m_0=\lim_k m_{n_k}\in M$. And we have 
$$
\|x-m_0\|=\lim_n\|x-m_n\|=d(x,M). 
$$